# semi-random set of subsets

Tags: algorithm, random, set

I'm trying to generate semi-random subsets with some restrictions.

Here are the variable descriptions with example values:

- ObjCount - the number of objects (12)
- VisibleCount (AKA SetSize) - the number of objects per set (6)
- SetCount - the number of sets (12)
- ObjAppearances - the number of set in which an object appears = `SetCount * VisibleCount / ObjCount`

I need to produce a given number of sets (SetCount) that follow these rules:

1. Each set is a collection of objects, but no object can be in a single set more than once.
2. Furthermore, each object should be in the same number of sets. *If it doesn't devide evenly, then the number sets in which an object appears can be off by 1 (some objects are in 4 sets, and others are in 5). I'll try to avoid this situation, so it's not critical.*

It's turning out to be far less trivial than I initially thought. Could anyone help me with some code/psuedocode? A solution to a generalized version would be very helpful too.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** VisibleCount is the set size. The number of times an object appears (ObjAppearances) is `SetCount * VisibleCount / ObjCount`

**Edit2:** I should also add that I want the sets to be fairly random. If the sets all have sequential objects (e.g. set1:5,6,7 set2:3,4,5 set3:10,11,0), the solution isn't useful. Sorry for not making that clear.

**Edit3:** Here is a solution that DOES NOT work. (In C#)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ObjectCount = 12;
    var SetSize = 6;
    var SetCount = 12;

    var Sets = Enumerable.Range(0, SetCount).Select(i => new List<int>()).ToArray(); // a SetCount-sized array of lists
    var ObjectAppearances = SetSize * SetCount / ObjectCount;
    var rand = new Random();

    // fill the sets
    for (int obj = 0; obj < ObjectCount; obj++)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < ObjectAppearances; a++)
        {
            // get the collection of sets that are not full
            var nonFullSets = Sets.Where(s => s.Count < SetSize);
            // get the collection of non-full sets without obj
            var setsWithoutObj = nonFullSets.Where(s => !s.Contains(obj));
            ///////////////////////
            // Here is the problem. All of the non-full sets may already 
            // have a copy of obj
            ///////////////////////
            // choose a set at random
            var currentSetIndex = rand.Next(setsWithoutObj.Count());
            var currentSet = setsWithoutObj.ElementAt(currentSetIndex);
            // add the object
            currentSet.Add(obj);
        }
    }

    // randomize the order within each set and output each
    for (int i = 0; i < SetCount; i++)
    {
        var randomlyOrderedSet = Sets[i].OrderBy(obj => rand.Next());
        Sets[i] = new List<int>(randomlyOrderedSet);

        // output
        foreach (var obj in Sets[i])
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0}, ", obj));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Here's the Solution - An implementation of MizardX's answer**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ObjectCount = 12;
    var SetSize = 6;
    var SetCount = 10;
    var rand = new Random();

    // make a matrix [SetCount][ObjectCount]
    var Matrix = new int[SetCount][];
    for (int s = 0; s < SetCount; s++)
        Matrix[s] = Enumerable.Repeat(0, ObjectCount).ToArray();

    // put approximately the same number of objects in each set by
    // adding sequential objects to sequential sets (not random)
    for (int s = 0; s < SetCount; s++)
    {
        var firstObject = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)s * ObjectCount / SetCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < SetSize; i++)
        {
            var o = (firstObject + i) % ObjectCount;
            Matrix[s][o] = 1;
        }
    }

    // output the result
    for (int s = 0; s < SetCount; s++)
    {
        for (int o = 0; o < ObjectCount; o++)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0}, ", Matrix[s][o]));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    // shuffle sets
    Matrix = Matrix.OrderBy(s => rand.Next()).ToArray();
    // make a new matrix for shuffle objects
    var objOrder = Enumerable.Range(0, ObjectCount).OrderBy(o => rand.Next()).ToArray();
    var MatrixSuffled = new int[SetCount][];
    for (int s = 0; s < SetCount; s++)
        MatrixSuffled[s] = Enumerable.Repeat(0, ObjectCount).ToArray();
    for (int o = 0; o < ObjectCount; o++)
    {
        var oldObj = o;
        var newObj = objOrder[o];
        for (int s = 0; s < SetCount; s++)
        {
            MatrixSuffled[s][newObj] = Matrix[s][oldObj];
        }
    }

    // check and output the result
    var objectCounters = Enumerable.Repeat(0, ObjectCount).ToArray();
    for (int s = 0; s < SetCount; s++)
    {
        var objectsInThisSet = 0;
        for (int o = 0; o < ObjectCount; o++)
        {
            objectsInThisSet += MatrixSuffled[s][o];
            objectCounters[o] += MatrixSuffled[s][o];
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0}, ", MatrixSuffled[s][o]));
        }
        Console.Write(string.Format("  {0}", objectsInThisSet));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    // output object count
    Console.WriteLine();
    for (int o = 0; o < ObjectCount; o++)
        Console.Write(string.Format("{0}  ", objectCounters[o]));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a **ObjCount** × **SetCount** matrix, and fill it with ones and zeros so that each column contains **VisibleCount** ones, and each row contains an (almost) equal number of ones. Order is irrelevant at this point.
2. Shuffle the columns (and the rows, if **ObjCount** does not divide **SetCount** × **VisibleCount** evenly).
3. For each column **i**, if the cell at row **j** equals 1, add object **j** to set **i**.

For 12 objects, 6 sets and 3 visible, the initial matrix might look like this:

```
1 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 1
```

And after shuffle:

```
1 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0
1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1
0 1 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Resulting in sets:

```
{1,3,8}
{3,5,11}
{1,7,8}
{4,6,9}
{2,4,10}
{10,11,12}
```

Comment: There are only so many distinct sets of sets you can get with your constraints. If you absolutely do not want a sequence, you could repeat the algorithm until you get a satisfactory result.

Answer (score 1):

Let `o` be the number of objects, `v` be the visibility count, `s` be the number of sets.

1. For each object [repeated `o` times]
     1.1. Repeat `v` times.
            1.1.1 Pick a set randomly and insert the object - do not reuse the set until step `1.1` ends.

EDIT: the solution fails as saroz indicates. The fix might be to pick the set with least count. If more than one set exists with that least count, pick one of those randomly.

Comment: I think this is close to the answer. If I change step 1.1 to "Repeat `ObjAppearances` times". And in step 1.1.1, I make sure to only choose from non-full sets. Give me a few minutes to confirm...

Comment: Not quite. I modified your solution a bit and posted it in the question. Thanks for the attempt though!

Answer (score 0):

```
resultSets = new Set[SetCount];  // create an array of sets to hold the results

totalObjectsPlaced = 0;
currentObjectIndex = 0;

while (totalObjectsPlaced < (ObjCount * VisibleCount)) {
  do {
    randomSet = rand(SetCount);
  } while (!resultSets[randomSet].contains(object[currentObjectIndex]));
  resultSets[randomSet].add(object[currentObjectIndex]);
  currentObjectIndex = (currentObjectIndex + 1) % ObjCount;
  totalObjectsPlaced++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The VisibleCount is the desired set size (sorry if that was unclear). The number of times that an object will appear is ObjCount/VisibleCount.    My other concern is that `(currentObjectIndex + 1) % ObjCount` will not produce a very random result.